# Create a bend div using css

Tags: css

I have an image created in phostoshop.Is it possible to create a design like this picture using pure css[image]

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using CSS for such shapes. You would be better of using SVG. Have a look at this thread for information on how to create such wavy shapes - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777470/wave-or-shape-with-border-on-css3/27780572#27780572

Answer (score 1):

You can draw through SVG which is HTML tag. You use CorelDraw to draw necessarily picture. Then you save with .svg format. Its svg tags copy your html file where is need