# I'm trying to achieve this curve effect using only CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve this curved effect using only HTML and CSS.

Any PointerS?

[image]

Comment: "display: none"

Comment: I'll chime in with border-radius

Comment: @Culyx issue is it not straight....

Comment: Well my joke now fails since OP added the image. lol

Comment: @Adebola this post will help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33035548/

Comment: The easiest way and fastest is to use this clip-path-maker, you can just play around. It saves a lot of time: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating s-shaped curve using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33035548/creating-s-shaped-curve-using-css)

Comment: @thebrownkid. Thanks. I guess I'll go with using a SVG.