# How to get this shape in CSS not in SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

I am creating a website, so I need to create a shape something like this. I am wondering how to do it in css and div.

[image: The shape that I need]

Thanks

Comment: This is not currently possible with CSS, you'll have to do it with and SVG

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, but i need it to be don in pure css because SVG not supporting in my mobile version

Comment: hi @harry, if this is question is duplicating, can you send me the url of that question, then I can get an answer from it. It is top urgent to me. Thanks

Comment: It is a duplicate and the link is provided. but still it is very high discouraged to use CSS for this purpose because its not supported very well and isnt possible with some crazy code which just isnt very responsive or moveable.

Comment: @P.S.F.Romesh: You should be able to find it in the bar at the top of this question. It will always appear at the top when a question is marked as dupe. But just to help you, here it is - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777470/wave-or-shape-with-border-on-css3. And as Stewart has mentioned above, I'd recommend you to look at the SVG answer (accepted one) in the linked thread.

Comment: @harry, thanks mate. very helpful. Thank you